# Deploying website with React frontend and Django rest framework backend

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework, web-deployment

I am deploying my first website and currently have it running locally with React on the front end communicating with the Django backend which has a database and a rest API.

I am now at the point I have been most concerned about. I need to find a way to get this onto an actual online service. Could I get some advice on what steps I need to take get this all online? And a suggestion on what services I should use?

For further details this is a hobbyist website that will likely not have much traffic. However, I don't mind spending a bit of money to get it running quickly and consistently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hosting the django app can be done either on heroku or on a cloud server (e.g. AWS or DigitalOcean). You can read from these two links.
https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/10/14/how-to-deploy-to-digital-ocean.html
https://medium.com/misfit-technologies/setting-up-a-ubuntu-16-04-production-server-for-a-basic-django-app-using-nginx-and-gunicorn-d8abe6e04520
The second link was written by me and it only covers the bare necessities of setting up nginx and gunicorn. I haven't hosted on heroku but as far as I've read they have good documentation so you might read those.

The best way to host your react website would be to use Firebase. This is free unless it exceeds a certain number of calls. To avoid unnecessary billing make sure to disable the site if it exceeds the call count. The easier way however would be to use heroku.
P.S. Heroku is free!

Comment: Personally, I can help you for the django app if you're hosting it in a cloud server so feel free to ask if you go that route!

Comment: Thanks for the response and the offer!


I think for now I will look into implementing both Django and React into Heroku. From what I am reading it is a pretty dynamic and easy to setup way to go. If I run into any limitations with that system I will look further into the other options you mentioned.

Comment: Sure, and also please upvote my answer if you found it helpful!

Comment: I can't upvote yet ! I tried. I will come back when I have enough points to do so.

Comment: @IanBarbour You can't up vote but you can accept one of the answers

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Heroku, with just $7/month per app. Or buy a cloud server in linode.